# "Add A Widget" button in the Customizer

Tags: theme-development, customization, widgets, theme-customizer

I'm developing a theme and working on the Customizer at the moment. I've been able to add sections, panels and controls to change text, colours and images.

One thing I've seen on other themes is an "Add A Widget" button which allows you to add widgets into the panel. There's an image below of the button in the Responsive Boat theme.

I'd like to add this into the Customizer in my theme but can't find any information on how to do it. Does anyone know how to do this or have any links to information about it?

[image: Add A Widget button in another theme]

Comment: I don't believe there's a way to allow widgets to be added to an arbitrary customiser section, bit it's simple to register a widget area. See [this article](http://devotepress.com/tutorials-hacks/wordpress-coding/how-to-register-sidebars-in-wordpress/). It just means that you'll add them in a separate section of the customiser.

Comment: I'd say just check into the coding of the theme in your example to see how they've done it and modify to your own purpose.

Comment: I've registered widget areas before but this isn't exactly what I'm looking to do. There must be a way to do it as this custom plugin has done it. I've looked through the code for the theme but I can't figure out what they do to get it to work.

Comment: @Ben_H have you found a way to do it? I'm looking for the same feature but can't find anywhere how to achieve it.

Comment: No, I never worked out how to do it. Just gave up and moved on!